# What makes rails never outputs `Set-Cookie` header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my `config/application.rb` file and somehow I made my Rails never outputs the `Set-Cookie` header anymore, failing all the session mechanisms.

What's wrong?

```
module KAPP
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost'
        { :namespace => 'fxs', :expires_in => 1.day, :compress => true }
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "k.tv"}
    config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "k.tv"}
    config.time_zone = 'Beijing'
    config.i18n.default_locale = 'zh-CN'
    config.i18n.available_locales = ['zh-CN', :en]
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.assets.prefix = ""
    config.action_controller.asset_host = nil
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's because of this malicious line

`config.assets.prefix = ""`

You will never want to set this to empty string.

Otherwise, visiting normal pages(like `/`) results in

`Served asset / - 404 Not Found (8ms)`

But still, the page can display, only without the `Set-Cookie` header, making the problem hard to identify.

Just set `config.assets.prefix` to nil.